# What information can you get with only a private IP address?

Tags: ip

I found a private IP address displayed on a video. What can you learn from a private IP address, if anything at all?

Comment: You can basically learn nothing from the private IP alone. Anybody can own use such IP address.

Comment: This is a little like asking, "what can you know about a house when you know one pet's name?"

Comment: OP, Does the IP address have four numbers in it, separated by dots?  If so, what is the first number?

Comment: Can we have a reality check here please: do you mean that an IP address that you know is in one of the private (RFC-1918 etc.) ranges, or that a numeric IP address has been displayed which you would normally consider to be private information?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by a "private" address?  How is a "private" address different from a normal address?

Comment: Actually, this is kind of like asking what information you can get from knowing that a person lives in house number 10. There are literally millions of houses number 10 in the world because that number can be reused by any street and city on the planet.

Answer (score 48):

Private IP addresses as defined by [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918.html) (`10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12` & `192.168.0.0/16`) can be used as anyone wishes, so a private IP address alone does not tell much and nothing is definite. However, many use the defaults from their router vendor, so on some occasions that might give a hunch on which kind of network equipment there are in use.

Again, any of the following is not definite and you would need to cross-check from other sources like the MAC address of the router or its login page. None of this information would be available on a video displaying just the IP address, so you would need an access to the network. Still, it is already some start for reconnaissance.

- `10.0.0.0/24`, `192.168.0.0/24`, `192.168.1.0/24` & `192.168.2.0/24` are so common that it could be anything.
- `10.8.0.0/24` suggests it might be an [OpenVPN with default configuration](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-6/).

If no link for another source, the following subnets are based on the articles from [TechSpot](https://www.techspot.com/guides/287-default-router-ip-addresses/) & [Software Testing Help](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/default-router-ip-address-list/), but ordered by subnets rather than brands. Brands are only listed for delimiting subnets.

| Subnet | Router Brand(s) |
| --- | --- |
| 10.0.0.0/24 | *More than 10 possibilities* |
| 10.0.1.0/24 | Apple, [WatchGuard Firebox](https://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/help-center/en-US/Content/en-US/Fireware/basicadmin/factory_default_about_c.html) |
| 10.1.1.0/24 | Belkin, D-Link |
| 10.10.1.0/24 | Asus |
| 10.90.90.0/24 | D-Link |
| 172.16.16.0/24 | [Sophos Firewall](https://doc.sophos.com/nsg/sophos-firewall/19.5/help/en-us/webhelp/onlinehelp/StartupHelp/Interfaces/index.html) |
| 192.168.0.0/24 | *More than 10 possibilities* |
| 192.168.1.0/24 | *More than 10 possibilities* |
| 192.168.2.0/24 | *More than 10 possibilities* |
| 192.168.3.0/24 | Amped Wireless, Huawei |
| 192.168.4.0/24 | Zoom, Zyxel |
| 192.168.8.0/24 | Eminent, Huawei |
| 192.168.10.0/24 | Motorola, NetComm, Repotec, Trendnet, Zoom, Zyxel |
| 192.168.11.0/24 | Buffalo |
| 192.168.15.0/24 | D-Link, Linksys, Motorola, Sweex |
| 192.168.16.0/24 | Repotec, Linksys |
| 192.168.20.0/24 | Motorola, NetComm |
| 192.168.30.0/24 | Motorola |
| 192.168.42.0/24 | [Android (USB Tethering)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46499) |
| 192.168.43.0/24 | [Android (WiFi Tethering)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46499) |
| 192.168.44.0/22 | [Android (Bluetooth Tethering)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46499) |
| 192.168.48.0/24 | [Android (Bluetooth Tethering)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46499) |
| 192.168.50.0/24 | Sweex |
| 192.168.55.0/24 | Sweex |
| 192.168.62.0/24 | Motorola |
| 192.168.86.0/24 | Google (only on Techspot article) |
| 192.168.88.0/24 | [MikroTik](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:First_time_startup) |
| 192.168.100.0/24 | Huawei, Motorola, Thomson, ZTE |
| 192.168.102.0/24 | Motorola |
| 192.168.123.0/24 | LevelOne |
| 192.168.168.0/24 | Sonicwall |
| 192.168.178.0/24 | [FRITZ!Box](https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-6840-int/19_Changing-the-FRITZ-Box-s-IP-address/) |
| 192.168.251.0/24 | Sweex |
| 192.168.254.0/24 | Actiontec |

The lists are not exhaustive.

Comment: 192.168.100.1 is the common address for most cable modems, so it's not meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I've updated the answer.

Comment: 192.168.178.0/24 is used by FritzBox.

Comment: 192.168.88.0/24 Mikrotik

Comment: @Barmar it strongly depends on which brand of modem and/or which ISP. 100 is absolutely not universal.

Comment: I have updated the list with more router brands that are now all based on a source. For additions to the list I would prefer a link to a source validating it is a common default configuration.

Comment: @Barmar: I wasn't able to find a source telling that 192.168.100.0/24 would be used more commonly in cable modems than those from Huawei, Motorola, Thomson & ZTE.

Comment: @user253751 From [ComputerWorld](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2880475/talk-to-your-modem.html): DSLReports has a [list of modems and their private IP addresses](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/7363?r=788). Most modems in their list use 192.168.100.1 but some use 10.0.0.1, 10.1.10.1 or 192.168.0.1.

Comment: @Barmar: The article suggests those aren't the **subnets** those devices would assign addressess from, but maybe a hidden routed network for the administrative interface. Hence, it might be a bit far from answering this question.

Comment: True, AFAIK it's the specific address `192.168.100.1`, I don't think the entire subnet is used for anything. But if you see that address in the video, it's a good bet it's a cable modem.

Comment: While it could be added as a single 192.168.100.1/32 address without the subnet, I think it would be enough and more describing to keep it here in the comments. An interesting finding, indeed!

Answer (score 13):

There's nothing that can be said with certainty, but it does help make *assumptions*:

- You can try deduce the smallest possible subnet: e.g. if you see 10.2.8.7 then one can assume that 10.2.8.1 - 10.2.8.254 might be reachable
- Seeing an address end in .1 or .254 might indicate the default gateway, and might, with some country or ISP specific info tell you which ISP they have (e.g. in the Netherlands 192.168.178.1 is usually the Fritz!Box gateway, and the ISPs that give Fritz!Boxes here are.. 2? 3? depending on the region even 1)
- It might help make assumptions about their LAN topology and location (usually where I come from 172.16/12 might be located in an educational institute, 10.x usually used by companies, 192.168.x.x usually personal homes)

Comment: Consider a /24 is not the smallest subnet.  It could be a /30, or in some cases a /31, or even a point to point address (though that is unlikely)

Answer (score 5):

You can learn that's it [private](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) (not routable on the Internet), that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can assume that if this RFC1918 IPv4 address is used to get to the internet at large, then there is a device somewhere in the path doing **NAT**.

That NAT device might be the router, and it might be doing DHCP and DNS and NTP services as well.

---

Or it could be fake info put there in a video for a laugh or a hidden message or "dog whistle".    There are some Nazi-related numbers that fit inside the 0-255 range.

Example:   My IP could be 10.69.420.1337    (but it isn't)

Comment: Your ip could not be `10.69.420.1337` FWIW.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze exactly right - if we saw that on screen it would be obviously done as a joke.   I didn't want to list the other kind of numbers I mentioned.

Comment: fair enough I wouldn't want to mention those either!